# How big should I declare my SQL Server column if it's going to hold an Article body?

Tags: sql-server

I'm going to save tutorials and snippets. How big should I declare the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare as  [varchar(max)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) (if the size will exceed 8,000 bytes). (or `nvarchar(max)` if supporting multi-byte character sets)

Answer (score 1):

`varchar(max)` or `nvarchar(max)`

[`TEXT(MAX)` or `NTEXT(MAX)` are being deprecated in future versions.]

Comment: ...as a follow-up; if you are storing any ligatures or non-unicode text, use nvarchar(max).

Comment: ...on Mitch's advice, varchar(max) or nvarchar(max).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean what datatype, probably you need nvarchar(max). If you are still on SQL Server 200 you need ntext or text.